# Do lvalue references hide undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior

I know that this is UB:

```
i = i++ + 1;
```

and indeed the clang 3.4 compiler issues a warning message on that line.

But in the following code it no longer does:

```
int i{}; // in global scope
int &f() {return i;}

int main()
{
    f() = i++ + 1;
}
```

Is this UB as well?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's undefined behavior as well, for the same reason: modification of `i` in `i++` is unsequenced relative to modification of `i` during the assignment.

Comment: (Ignore my previous comment, I misread the question, I though `f()` modified `i`)

Comment: I thought so. Thanks for confirming.